# Stata: combining regression results with other results

Tags: stata, data-analysis

I am trying to replicate some results from a study. therefore often i need to compare my regression results with results from the study that i'm trying to replicate. 
I have been manually combining my esttab results with the study results in excel. this however is tedious since i'm working with lot of variables. I was wondering whether there is a way to store the study results and then calling them to go next to my regression results. I tried storing them as scalars and calling them using estout however this puts the stored scalars below the regression results. i would prefer to have them side by side as another column.

Example:

Reference study results are

```
var b
x  2.1
z  4.2
```

I entered these into Stata

```
estadd scalar x=2.1
estadd scalar z=4.2
```

My regression is

```
eststore: reg y x z
estout, stats(x,z)
```

but when i do this i get a table like this

```
var        b
my reg x   5.3
my reg z   2.3
scalar x   2.1
scalar z   4.2
```

But I would want the results like this

```
var        b      scalar b
my reg x   5.3     2.1
my reg z   2.3     4.2
```

Comment: You may be lucky and find that someone wants to answer this, but I think it's out of place here. If you showed a specific problem with specific code and wanted specific advice on improving it or fixing it, your chances might be better. See general advice at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic [Personal note: I see that I've tried to answer all 2 of your previous questions, so I contribute positively too.]

Comment: i dont fully understand when you say this is out of place. and to clarify my problem i have point estimates from reference regression. I would like to combine these estimates to the regression table created using the esttab command so i can compare my results with the reference estimates ( I can't run the reference regression because it uses a different data set. however the variables are the same in both regressions). hope this clarifies the problems

Comment: Please study the help page cited and consider the criteria: a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers ... is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Comment: I think if you create a toy example of an existing table and one that is created by esttab (i.e., two or more separate tex or txt files), there will be a *nix way to merge the two from the command line or shell script. I would also include what you want the output to look like and your OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following might help. Find comments inline.

```
clear 
set more off

*----- example data -----

sysuse auto
keep price weight mpg

*----- what you want -----

//regress and store
reg price weight mpg 
eststo m1

// create matrix of "scalars"
matrix w = (2.1 , 2.4 , 3.2) 

// rename matrix columns to coincide with those of regression
mat colnames w = weight mpg _cons 

// add
estadd matrix w

// print
estout m1, cells("b w")
```