# Add bootstrapped p-value to esttab

Tags: formatting, format, stata

I bootstrapped my own p-values for a regression and now need to add them to my esttab table. I would ideally like the p-values to appear immediately below the coefficient point estimates. While I am able to place the new p-values into my table, they appear in the table is if they arenew point estimates with labels c1, c2, etc.

Here is the relevant simplified code (following the regression) where the bootstrapped p-value is in the local newpvalue

```
matrix pval = (`newpvalue') 
estadd matrix Puse = pval
esttab , replace  cells(b(star fmt(3)) Puse(fmt(3) par) )
```

This code produces the standard table, but with the p-value placed several spaces below the coefficient estimate. Thanks very much for any help, and please let me know if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

An example that might help (with in-line comments):

```
clear 
set more off

*----- example data -----

sysuse auto
keep price weight mpg

*----- what you want -----

//regress and store
reg price weight mpg 
eststo m1

// create matrix of "scalars"
matrix s = (2.1 , 2.4 , 3.2)  

// rename matrix columns to coincide with those of regression
mat colnames s = weight mpg _cons 

// add
estadd matrix s

// print
estout m1, cells(b s)
```

Very similar to: [Stata: combining regression results with other results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168113/stata-combining-regression-results-with-other-results) but notice the absence of quotes in the last line of code.